# Can I revenge a second time after I fail?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I just revenged attacked and failed miserably. Is it possible to redeem myself and attack him again?

Comment: Nope, you have only one shot at revenge.

Comment: You should have noticed that _revenge not available_ text replacing the revenge button.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't attack him again ... 
This was made to protect villages from loads of attacks in a row.

Comment: Err why was this down voted ? Seems like a pretty straight forward answer.

Comment: @GoodSp33d check the edit...